Scheduled Paths on Record-Trigger Flow -- Appears to be only one per object per flow
I'm working on a record-trigger flow with a Scheduled Path.  I've observed something and want to confirm it's expected behavior.
I update a record, I see an entry Setup->Time-Based Workflow.

I then update the record which should schedule a new step.  I then check Setup->Time-Based Workflow.  I see that the entry has changed.  The time is different.  (The record inside SF that represents the deferred step is not directly accessible so I can't tell if it deleted the old entry and added a new one or if it updated the record; but that is moot as the effect is the same).

So I'm thinking only one copy of the time-deferred path can be queued per object.  That isn't a big issue for me as in this use-case, sending a reminder, I only want the most-recent one to run.  I actually coded a step to double check the datetime and do nothing if the time is not the correct time.  I may actually not need that step if I confirm that only the latest copy of the path from the latest update runs.
